# IF check that adds missing MAC address zeros

Tags: c++, visual-studio

MAC addresses stored in cMac variable such as:

```
"1C:0D:86:2A:B8:0F"
```

are missing leading zeros:

```
"1C:D:86:2A:B8:F"
```

I want to make an IF check before cout and add zeros if missing:

```
char cMac[19];
int a, b, c, d, e, f;

...

if (sscanf_s(cMac, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f) == 6)
      sprintf_s(cMac, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", a, b, c, d, e, f);

cout << cMac << endl;
```

Comment: Why not make sure the zeroes are there from the beginning, when first formatting `cMac`?

Comment: Because sadly I am a C++ beginner and I need to fix it in other person's code, so I thought it would do the trick and it won't necesseraly slow execution that much.

Comment: Actually, when inserting those zeroes later, you have to move the characters that follow. That's slower than doing while formatting. While formatting the first byte, you have't yet printed the second byte so there's nothing to move. More importantly, it's not just faster but also easier there.